# How to crawl news websites (content only)?

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, hierarchical-clustering

I want to crawl Indian news websites and their archives (eg. thehindu.com, indianexpress.com and timesofindia.com).

I have heard of boilerplate library in Java used to extract content. But is there any library in python to do this and how t do this?

If this is a repeat question, please help me to point out.

Comment: The title of your question gives some pretty good pointers on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+crawl+news+websites+(content+only)+python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is a popular scraping framework for Python